# After updating Rails and Devise I get "undefined method `[]='(....)" on validating email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We recently updated Devise from 3.1.4 to 3.3.0 (we are on Rails version 4.1.4). This created a bug in a previously working email-validation, causing

```
lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb #apply_to_attribute_or_variable(attr, method)
```

to fail on the following line:

```
self[attr] = self[attr].try(method)
```

it seems like it's no longer able to set a value in the self-object.

Does anybody have any experience with this? Are there some other Devise modules that are needed?